# Class 'App\Imports\FirstSheetImport' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

**Hola** Estoy tratando de ingresar unos datos por medio de un archivo de `excel` pero necesito que me importe de una hoja especifica, estuve consultando la documentación de `laravel excel 3.1` pero no entiendo muy bien como hacerlo, tengo lo siguiente:

Controlador import:

```
class Import implements WithMultipleSheets 
{
    public function sheets(): array
    {
        return [
            'importar' => new InstrumentosImport(),
            'importar' => new CalibracionImport(),
        ];
    }
}
```

InstrumentosImport (controlador)

```
class InstrumentosImport implements ToModel,WithHeadingRow
{


    public function model(array $row)
    {
        $tipo = tbl_tipo_instrumento::firstOrCreate([
            'tipo_nombre' => $row['tipoinstrumento']
        ]);
        //dd($row);
        //dd($row['tipo']); //ver si el dato llega
        //Si no encuentra el dato en la tabla lo crea

        /*$tipo = tbl_tipo_instrumento::firstOrCreate(
            ['tipo_nombre' => $row['tipoinstrumento']],//busca
            ['tipo_nombre'=>$row['tipoinstrumento']] //crea
        );*/

        $marca = tbl_marca::firstOrCreate(
            ['mar_nombre' => $row['marca']],
            ['mar_nombre'=>$row['marca']]
        );

        $id = Auth::id(); //trae el id del usuario logeado

        return new tbl_instrumentos([
            'ins_codigo'   => $row['codigo'],
            'ins_observacionInicial'   => $row['observacioninicial'],
            'ins_proximaCalibracion'=>$row['proximacalibracion'],
            'ins_fechaUltimaCalibracion'=>$row['ultimacalibracion'],
            'ins_claseOexactitud'    => $row['claseoexactitud'],
            'ins_nSerie' => $row['nserie'],
            'ins_divOescala'=>$row['divoescala'],
            'ins_consecutivoInterno' => $row['consecutivointerno'],
            'ins_observaciones' =>$row['observaciones'],
            'ins_observacionFinal' => $row['observacionfinal'],
            'ins_magnitud' => $row['magnitud'],
            'ins_modelo' => $row['modelo'],
            'ins_codActividad' => $row['codigoactividad'],
            'ins_area' => 'null',
            'ins_usu_id' =>  $id,
            'ins_tipo_id' => $tipo->tipo_id,
            'ins_mar_id' => $marca->mar_id,
        ]);
    }
    public function headingRow(): int
    {
        return 5;
    }
```

No me queda muy claro si la funcion sheets tendria que ponerla en la parte de mi instrumentos import o ahí donde la deje esta bien, o me toque hacerle un cambio en esta linea que tengo en el controlador principal
`Excel::import(new InstrumentosImport,$request->import_file);`

Comment: Creaste las clases FirstSheetImport y SecondSheetImport? https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/multiple-sheets.html

Comment: Me habia saltado ese paso sin querer, gracias ya funciona.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Hola, Ayer pense que funcionaba porque me salio mensaje de que se importaron los datos pero hoy que lo probe de nuevo me fije que manda el mensaje pero en mi base de datos no inserta

Comment: Y le pusiste que inserte los datos?

Comment: En que parte te refieres? tengo la funcion de la hoja y abajo tengo la funcion que almacena los datos esto en el controlador import. Y en el controlador principal tengo lo siguiente `Excel::import(new InstrumentosImport,$request->import_file);`

Comment: O sea, en la clase FirstSheetImport tenés la función `model` que inserta los datos? Y la llamás desde la clase InstrumentosImport? no sé, sin ver lo que hiciste es como tratar de adivinar

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Creo que me he confundido, bueno te cuento en mi instrumentosImport tengo la funcion sheets arriba de la funcion model  y el FirstSheetImport lo tengo vacio

Comment: Revisa el link a la documentación que te pasé en el primer comentario. En InstrumentosImport le indicas cuales son las hojas que quieres en el método `sheets`. Y en cada clase para importar hojas, va la función `model` con la lógica para insertar las filas. Si te trabas con algo, actualiza la pregunta con lo que tienes

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ No me queda muy claro sin embargo edite la pregunta para ver si así me puedes guiar mas facil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [Múltiples Hojas](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/multiple-sheets.html#multiple-sheets)

Cuando un archivo tiene varias hojas, cada hoja pasará por el objeto de importación. Si deseas manejar cada hoja por separado, deberás implementar el concern `WithMultipleSheets`.

El método `sheets()` espera que se devuelva una matriz de objetos de importación de hoja.

Si solo conoces el nombre de la hoja de trabajo, puedes usar el nombre de la hoja de trabajo como selector. Pon el nombre de la hoja de trabajo como índice de matriz para vincular esa hoja de trabajo a su objeto de importación de hojas.

**Entonces si tu hoja se llama `importar`**, puedes hacer lo siguiente.

```
class ImportarExcel implements WithMultipleSheets 
{
    public function sheets(): array
    {
        return [
            'importar' => new InstrumentosImport(),
        ];
    }
}
```

Una clase de importación de hojas puede importar los mismas concerns que un objeto de importación normal.

**Entonces si tu clase se llama `InstrumentosImport`**, ahí pones la función `model` en la que insertas los datos.

```
class InstrumentosImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow
{
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        $tipo = tbl_tipo_instrumento::firstOrCreate([
            'tipo_nombre' => $row['tipoinstrumento']
        ]);

        $marca = tbl_marca::firstOrCreate(
            ['mar_nombre' => $row['marca']],
            ['mar_nombre'=>$row['marca']]
        );

        $id = Auth::id();

        return new tbl_instrumentos([
            'ins_codigo'   => $row['codigo'],
            'ins_observacionInicial'   => $row['observacioninicial'],
            'ins_proximaCalibracion'=>$row['proximacalibracion'],
            'ins_fechaUltimaCalibracion'=>$row['ultimacalibracion'],
            'ins_claseOexactitud'    => $row['claseoexactitud'],
            'ins_nSerie' => $row['nserie'],
            'ins_divOescala'=>$row['divoescala'],
            'ins_consecutivoInterno' => $row['consecutivointerno'],
            'ins_observaciones' =>$row['observaciones'],
            'ins_observacionFinal' => $row['observacionfinal'],
            'ins_magnitud' => $row['magnitud'],
            'ins_modelo' => $row['modelo'],
            'ins_codActividad' => $row['codigoactividad'],
            'ins_area' => 'null',
            'ins_usu_id' =>  $id,
            'ins_tipo_id' => $tipo->tipo_id,
            'ins_mar_id' => $marca->mar_id,
        ]);
    }

    public function headingRow(): int
    {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Finalmente, **en el Controlador llamas a la clase principal**, que aquí le cambié el nombre a `ImportarExcel` para evitar ambigüedades con alguna otra clase que también pueda llamarse Import.

```
Excel::import(new ImportarExcel, $request->import_file);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ya me quedo super claro, y funciona perfectamente

Comment: @RafaelMonroyRodriguez Genial. No puse la clase CalibracionImport porque no la agregaste a la pregunta, pero sería la misma lógica que con InstrumentosImport.

Comment: Si correcto use la misma logica y funciono